# Vim, ctags and overloading

Tags: tags, ctags, filetype-c++

Is there a way to make vim jump to the right matching definition *automatically* in case of multiple definitions. Our C++ code heavily uses function overloading and vim's handling of ctags does not seems to be ready for it.

For example,

```
void abc(int a, int b) {

}

void abc(int a, int b, int c) {

}
```

Strangely, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> on

```
abc(1,2,3);
```

takes to the 1st definition and not the correct definition which is the 2nd. Also, <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> prompts for options but that's not what I am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The documentation (`:help ctrl-]`) says:

```
When there are several matching tags for {ident}, jump
to the [count] one.  When no [count] is given the
first one is jumped to.
```

`g]` may not be what you are looking for but that's the best you can get in Vim.

Basically, you can't expect ctags and Vim to *understand* your code, so you'll have to look for a smarter indexer (like cscope, GNU GLOBAL, or something based on clang) or use an actual IDE.

Answer (score 1):

### [clangd](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/index.html) & [vim-lsp](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp)

I have tested `clangd` to see whether overloaded functions are actually distinguished when looking for the correct definition from a code line where one of the overloaded functions is used. In my minimal testing configuration using the vim plugin `vim-lsp` it worked.

#### Minimal Configuration

`$MYVIMRC` is

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
if executable('/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.0/bin/clangd')
    augroup Clangd
        autocmd User lsp_setup call lsp#register_server({
            \ 'name': 'clangd',
            \ 'cmd': {server_info->['/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.0/bin/clangd']},
            \ 'whitelist': ['c', 'cpp', 'objc', 'objcpp'],
            \ })
        autocmd FileType c,cpp,objc,objcpp nmap <buffer> gd <plug>(lsp-definition)
        autocmd FileType c,cpp,objc,objcpp setlocal omnifunc=lsp#complete
    augroup END
endif
```

Installation of `vim-lsp` which requires `async.vim` into vim8 packpath

```
$ cd ~/.vim
$ git clone https://github.com/prabirshrestha/async.vim pack/prabirshrestha/start/async.vim/
$ git clone https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp   pack/prabirshrestha/start/vim-lsp/
```

Now your vim configuration should look like (omitting more deeply nested files and folders)

```
~/.vim
❯ tree -L 4 -F
.
├── pack/
│   └── prabirshrestha/
│       └── start/
│           ├── async.vim/
│           └── vim-lsp/
└── vimrc

5 directories, 1 file
```

#### Test

Now consider the cpp file

```
void abc(int a, int b) {

}

void abc(int a, int b, int c) {

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    abc(1,2);
    abc(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Pressing `gd` on `abc` of

- `abc(1,2)` jumps to first line, and of
- `abc(1,2,3)` jumps to fifth line.

**Environment and versions:**

- `vim`: MacVim 8.1.950 (155); installed from DMG from [github](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases) on macOS 10.14.3
- `clangd`: 7.0.0; installed with `$ brew install llvm` (not in `$PATH` by default, use absolute path)
- `vim-lsp`: [e3f6933](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp/tree/e3f69339efbf9582be1859766e2b2ed353bedfbc) (Mar 7, 2019)
  and `async.vim`: [f301455](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/async.vim/tree/f3014550d7a799097e56b094104dd2cd66cf2612) (Feb 13, 2019)

Answer (score 0):

As romanl  stated, `ctags` doesn't really understand the code, so the best it can do is point you to functions sharing the name you're searching on.

However, I believe the `clang_complete` plugin provides the functionality you seek.  It makes use of the `clang` compiler to find the function that actually matches the one you are searching for, and not just one that shares the same name.  It will override the `ctrl-]` functionality of `ctags`.

I have also seen it stated that `YouCompleteMe` renders `clang_complete` outmoded, but as I have yet to use it myself, I cannot guarantee its utility.

clang_complete git repo: https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete

Comment: I can't tell about *clang_complete*, however, YCM cannot find a function definition defined (sic) in another translation unit. We have (/had) clang-indexer (not really maintained), and a few other plugins. Nowadays, I'd say to check clangd + plugins implementing Language Server Protocol.