# Ctags function overload

Tags: ctags

I wanted to test if I can handle working on C++ projects in vim (well actually neovim). These were the core features, that I wanted to have:

- syntax highlighting
- window splitting
- go to definition
- autocompletion

The first two ones are obvious, so I got to setting up the third. I already knew about ctags, but I wanted to check if it works for me. I created two files:

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.hpp"

void foo(int* a)
{
    (*a)++;
}


int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    foo(&a);
    bar(a);
    bar(5.0);
}
```

test.hpp:

```
void bar(int i)
{

}

void bar(double d)
{

}
```

By running `ctags ./*`, I created the corresponding `tags` file:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_MODE   u-ctags /u-ctags or e-ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Universal Ctags Team    //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Universal Ctags /Derived from Exuberant Ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   https://ctags.io/   /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   0.0.0   /45968eff/
bar ./test.hpp  /^void bar(double d)$/;"    f   typeref:typename:void
bar ./test.hpp  /^void bar(int i)$/;"   f   typeref:typename:void
foo ./test.cpp  /^void foo(int* a)$/;"  f   typeref:typename:void
main    ./test.cpp  /^int main()$/;"    f   typeref:typename:int
```

So being in `main` and pressing `Ctrl-]` on `foo(&a)` jumps straight to the right function. The problem is, that when I am on `bar(a)` and I do that, the windows switches to `test.hpp`, but the `double d` overload of the function is selected (I know it could through implicit conversion, but I have a better overload), not the one taking an int as an argument.

So my question here is: can I somehow configure vim or ctags to make it so I jump to a proper definition when using vim?

Comment: BTW I could not find quickly whether one of the newer language server for c++ ([clangd](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/Features.html#find-definition-declaration), [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls#ccls)/[cquery](https://github.com/cquery-project/cquery#cquery)) support finding the correct overloaded function definition. Afaik, ctags will never support this. It only considers the identifier under the cursor and no context. The [new parser in universal-ctags](http://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/parser-cxx.html#cxx) does not change this.

Comment: I have tried `clangd` and for me it actually did the trick. You find my test as an answer in the referenced question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19153/1292