# Plugin to display a smarter method tag list

Tags: ctags, filetype-c++

Note this may be a duplicate, but I couldn't really find an answer.

From a C++ perspective:

With universal ctags on, doing a `C-]` on top of a method call presents you with a tag list matching the method name. Some of the methods in that list may be from different classes, some of them may be overloaded with either incompatible types or incorrect number of arguments compared to the original method.

**Is there a plugin out there which removes some of the false positives or at the very least sorts this list in a smarter way? Something similar to what CLion cmake engine does?**

I'm not interested in autocompletion as that works for me.

Comment: have you tried the taglist plugin?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I have looked at taglist, however I've settled with the tagbar plugin (an alternative to taglist) to provide me with an overview of the current file structure.

Comment: Note there is the question [Vim, ctags and overloading](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7561/1292). Today a possible solution is to use a c++ language server and a vim lsp plugin. There is an answer from me describing [vim-lsp together with clangd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19153/1292).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot provide an answer different to the one I gave in other similar questions.

While tag-based plugins may present a complete list of existing overloads in a way much more ergonomic than `:tselect` (they may even provide a filter option like my [lh-tags](https://github.com/luchermitte/lh-tags) plugin), they cannot help restrict the list of overloads to the one matching the types of the objects involved.

Well, they could. This would means they have parsed the current C++ code and built an associated [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). At this point, these plugins would have access to much better tools than tags, so they don't bother with tags. That's what [language server protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) (LSP) [plugins](https://langserver.org/#implementations-client) offer.

Lately, I've been using [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) + [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/wiki), the result is often much better that what I had with tag-based solutions to navigate C++ codes.